# (JS/TS) Why my generator function code have different behavior on the idempotence?

Tags: javascript, typescript, stream, iterator, generator

#### Define

Here is a lazy sequence define by generator func:

```
type Fn <T, R> = (p: T) => R ;

class Stream
<T> 
{
    
    constructor 
    (private readonly generatorFunction: () => Generator<T>) 
    {} ;
    
    
    static readonly iterate = 
    <T,> (initHead: T, f: Fn<T, T>)
    : Stream<T> => 
        
        new Stream
        ( function* ()
        : Generator<T> 
        {
            let head = initHead;
            while (true) 
            {
                yield head ;
                head = f(head);
            } ;
        } ) ;
    
    
    readonly map = 
    <R,> (f: Fn<T, R>)
    : Stream<R> => 
        
        new Stream
        (( function* (this: Stream<T>)
        : Generator<R> 
        {
            const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                yield f(head) ;
            } ;
        } ).bind(this)) ;
    
    
    
    readonly tookUntil = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : [T[], Stream<T>] => 
    {
        const result: T[] = [] ;
        const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
        
        while (true) 
        {
            const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
            if (done) break;
            
            result.push(head);
            if (when(head)) break;
        } ;
        
        const drops = iterator ;
        
        return [result, new Stream
        (( function* (this: Stream<T>)
        : Generator<T> 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value, done } = drops.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                yield value ;
            }
        } ).bind(this)), ] ;
    } ;
    
    readonly took = 
    (limit: number)
    : [T[], Stream<T>] => 
    {
        if (limit < 1) 
        { return [[], this.follow({} as T).took(1)[1]] ; } else 
        {
            let count = 1;
            return this.tookUntil(() => !(count++ < limit));
        } ;
    } ;
    
    
    readonly takeUntil = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : T[] => 
        
        this.tookUntil(when)[0] ;
    
    readonly take = 
    (n: number)
    : T[] => 
        
        this.took(n)[0] ;
    
    
    readonly droppingUntil = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : Stream<T> => 
        
        this.tookUntil(when)[1] ;
    
    readonly dropping = 
    (limit: number)
    : Stream<T> => 
        
        this.took(limit)[1] ;
    
    
    
    readonly dropUntil = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : Stream<T> => 
        
        new Stream
        (( function* (this: Stream<T>)
        : Generator<T> 
        {
            const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                if (when(head)) { yield head ; break; } ;
            } ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                yield value ;
            } ;
        } ).bind(this)) ;
    
    readonly drop = 
    (limit: number)
    : Stream<T> => 
    {
        const the = this ;
        return new Stream(function* () 
        {
            if (limit < 1) 
            { yield* the.generatorFunction() ; } else 
            {
                let count = 1;
                yield* the.dropUntil(() => (count++ > limit));
            } ;
        }) ;
    } ;
    
    
    
    // some code not very important here ...
    
    
    
    [Symbol.iterator] = () => this.generatorFunction() ;
} ;
```

#### Tests

Method `drop` implemented directly:

```
const droppedUntil = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).dropUntil(x => x > 3) ;
console.log(droppedUntil.take(10)); // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
console.log(droppedUntil.take(10)); // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

```
const dropped = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).drop(7) ;
console.log(dropped.take(10)); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
console.log(dropped.take(10)); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Method `dropping` implemented by `took`:

```
const dropped_bytook = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).droppingUntil(x => !(x < 2)) ;
console.log(dropped_bytook.take(10)); // [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
console.log(dropped_bytook.take(10)); // [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22] ？？？？
```

And some other funny things ...

```
const fibonacci = Stream.iterate([0, 1], ([a, b]) => [b, a + b]).map(([x]) => x) ;
console.log(fibonacci.take(6 + 4 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 4 + 2)); 
// [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657]

const xs = fibonacci.dropping(6).drop(4).map(x => [x]) ;
const xxs = fibonacci.dropping(6).map(x => [x]).drop(4) ;

console.log(xs.take(2)); // [[55], [89]] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(xs.take(2)); // [[987], [1597]] ： 4 more dropped with no more map before take ... 
console.log(xs.take(2)); // [[17711], [28657]] ； 4 more dropped with no more map before take ...

console.log(xxs.take(2)); // [[55], [89]] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(xxs.take(2)); // [[987], [1597]] ： 4 more dropped with no more map before take ... 
console.log(xxs.take(2)); // [[17711], [28657]] ； 4 more dropped with no more map before take ...


const ys = fibonacci.dropping(6).dropping(4).map(x => [x]) ;
const yys = fibonacci.dropping(6).map(x => [x]).dropping(4) ;

console.log(ys.take(2)); // [[55], [89] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(ys.take(2)); // [[144], [233]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...
console.log(ys.take(2)); // [[377], [610]]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...

console.log(yys.take(2)); // [[55], [89] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(yys.take(2)); // [[144], [233]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...
console.log(yys.take(2)); // [[377], [610]]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...

const zs = fibonacci.dropping(5).map(x => [x]).drop(4).dropping(1) ;
const zzs = fibonacci.dropping(6).map(x => [x]).drop(4).dropping(0) ;

console.log(zs.take(2)); // [[55], [89] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(zs.take(2)); // [[144], [233]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...
console.log(zs.take(2)); // [[377], [610]]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...

console.log(zzs.take(2)); // [[55], [89] ： 10 dropped with map once, and ...
console.log(zzs.take(2)); // [[144], [233]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...
console.log(zzs.take(2)); // [[377], [610]]] ： just take 2 then, no more dropped ...
```

#### Summary

So, there is two type of `Stream`:

- one is looks ***immutable***: its `take` method don't have side effect.
- and one is looks ***mutable*** if you made it by `dropping`: its `take` method have side effect for the `stream` instance itself.

The question is, why the `take` of stream that returns by `took` or `tookUntil` looks unpure, but all the `take` of stream that returns by other methods **that also created by the same form `new Stream(( function* (this: Stream<T>): Generator<T> { /* ... some yields ... */ } ).bind(this))`** won't make side effect for this instance itself.

---

I tried all my code at the [*TS Playground (v5.1.6)*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), Here is my tests: [https://tsplay.dev/Wklk0w](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true&ssl=283&ssc=1&pln=242&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAPAFQDRQEoD4oF4oAUYAXFMgJR44ZQDcAsAFBMDGANgIYDOXUAysABOEDgFsmKHEwDeTKPKhyFLAPZwuQgK4tgKwYsYLCYQQEsAbh2DRhHACZq2IKAHMIcCIKt6YmuDtM1UgJKXBwAcXdPb0FJSiV5aQBfOgSDIzSNK1MWKFsHOCcoU2svazx0hRRUHAJTOBKACRE7UjQoADNSeGqyLHI00gFbUUkqSqN5NKMPAHd+IRFxQ0n5Ak6-ALUAKkIBldXSSI8yvTHphVkD1YU2CGAoAAsWivqmloZrm6hZx9M7whaCDxL43K7fb4gUwQNh2J4vT4Qm7PewVDoEFF2ciIpFQFI41YpSgEiak-KOZyiDhgCppRAYGqELqwOC9bD7IxDRZiek4MKkjKg+RzBYjC5rdYdTbAQJwXYEYB-LhckZxcVQI5RU6xbACy7qoyqdQPErRXT6fCK0xcAB0bhOMV8-hlahCqSFk1+-2gCsEmmBetW4NxhrUGig0igljY-tImPQBWgKXwpu1No8AA9gCESSHTB1CInKAAjWwAa1zuINNyhMLh6MxxOr8nx6qJNuL9TsCqV5Cb1zSg+u5MKzl0KjLAFU4DK2LTrgRfu5uqz2sWVCo7hw4P1BlAANrIfcAXXQwyWkmP4zSwdWRvDwi4mjYwDaJ4q78r8nvJtKMQqVq2vaZo+NKspul+gY-H8AK+v6ILfLeEI-hGUYcDGEBxi0CZqEmrx-ua6YQFmObNsUBYEEWUCliIFZkWRj7PsANpgJoXCPBiLTYmR+aEEucCcfYfbUeWkGth66ooXYggqGAvApgRejut86rCMAmiCAg+6MS+6AiueYjqgQkpgTsgJKiqF7ILuHqag65rnB6SHfF6sFAghuLObiKGRtG-o4R4eIVNJsm2pm2bcR63y8ZRuElqJZGCiGRi1rCaEYcpuJJG2UDkB2XY9tafboFeJLiUlCgjkU45lvORgEGwpiiCUpBwJoojFp4HIKKQh4nme3KjNZV78je6oxY1zUPIgUAAIweUGeT3BpWn9VAgE2h0m5sCoswEMkUDcGQeU1QQ837rNx6lUFMJcNA6peasdwPKofgPPgs2QUYakretSo2jV06zsZoQ4AAhAQr0zgA1NDSBQJNJR9mJmUtqjpJpFVY4cGWEBA-8dUKIuzxwCuvTrpuIg7t18hviNUgSR6G2AzO-zE+45D7gADKVQ7fS0FLrTj0D4GkBCk1AbUdV1e5HvTUHqszG5luLnM8+jfOVQLo5QCFYBgPULj43OosLvxZNrhuW7U3uBlDXyDMqUz-0s8D-Gc5dGvDtrRR6wbcAuITayI6+kvtZ1gg0xqopWQ7CvO9aAPKw1TVIxdvMDpnFXyFjusyWAxtB3xJMW+gFPWzZnIxzy1nXoz3z6YNRkmc6sryoBlk15XNx2SBsS1w9ZEoam-6Wv9wHak6WwCf2IZka5PruVBRiPchYYPL56GxvC9gBXhCl90RJGRclCgxVRNE419NyJWfFH8YJWKUJGqVwpidAibRtBBdfaO-8vCgF6Aj9AGMiq9vg+XSv5XWuEgoHzTOFUiUUbjnzip-K+t8pjINWK-KB0B-7lRuO2TscBuyAWEiSTGPtnB6yLinKarVw4y2uJ3e2dcV6SXXn9EWf1rTo35upTSksIDzDtgQKUrczJukHtg8ihAQ7w3mgAxIUBX67EVBAO0WpHSmRnh-FIt17qyPATcZ6UAobvTmv-FK0JYTqOeDaPWxsQbjEhioN6sMoA4BDsjMihDCSzwUP4jGWcFAAHowlQC4CoUQ0BVB2GgHAFQDxzCeGcE1MAehgDbgeM8YQUAbSFM1jnahUSWDbjocyAgHAWAsDaOgDMbRQbHVtoNMYo1643EbmKD0xkNiSLlOZa0rC1S2SgMcPujlEJDy4SPc0AFx7aPNFPF0ej-6QL8phHedg95wOKIpQQR8Ir-1QR4SgP1NL-zImYmpuR8CYn-rg25-Cb6yKAXBUBxjMHmK4ZvDCWFd4wMCsmfZh9EEn1PnI2KZz0F0VkdnZKzz8DoluegRs1iFBPNqS8wkOKgp5RIWQ3sgSsEItzltNKpt6pVNufUqAjTjrjHaG8YAzR7BNNaaqWuHSnYNxEdXZY3w+kSOnu3CyArRnfF7tqKZYJ6KyNwSytlcJHm2LsPYxOXBykCQ6CSiEOUCUFXIXq4pS17CCwpTteYVKiaYg5SwiV3LHavO+BtCl3YCAAH0GnNIzGiriXsEVpH3HwEAHVNw2jmXoEaexxgbQnjogZEEmDiVYGGSmNodouAIAAIgALQFsLUW4teac37CYBEvOsliiiDAHcWJM5damGEDoJwTA03GirfrCAdhC74DtpGgiEACAACYGnjAzFAOG81HH52cZO-kk6cAAGZ+z3gzVmyi+dIC9tZmwAGwszpc2RlASt+4AAs6AACs6AABs6AADs6AAAc6AACc6BZpc0-bNT9Y65rLuPB26JdxM0qGzX7HtxsD24yPSes9l6oA3qgPeqAT6oCvqgB+ua365q-rmv+2agH22MCktuntFQB1zOHf+hdOBJ3TrynrAgD613ptA5uyDdgYPDq-fByJ+5sNfp-X+z9y7P2Idmsh2aqHZrodms+oDpH2OaM4+R7j2TYN8exKegTQncOzXw7NQj4m5qSek7J+TimSPro4+B3NJaC1lpI5Wv2hsa11ogA2h4xYxzKwKUU5gynO1cc9b5mqlHBqDrNDR8di6p1zSY9uw287xgQ0nTNEdFDgMbvs6F8LyseNwZ02e0ziHkOofQ5h-TImCNKds6pvL6mwsgBqkV7T38z1EYk5+izn6rOfuwyO3DI78MjpHVeQA+P-Tcmy5yJ0TYlWgDsUGcngIAaHc4Um0NmuEdFMOuOAtzTCRZGNFsow7uaftPIQfcHAy7HmafuYs6AOAJeLA9m0VIwDGX3BmB7E62PqFy9mvbB2jtFdvQl89CWR1Q5h3DuGWWdMVoEwZz96B-2meQ5h7rUBRvoGXeV7HQnz2IZHcu0zy6H3odvcJrDz75NXrfehkdV7n2IfPQp-Dt6H23uk1zN957LMPsMxj59fOH1KeAw8DM8lOj7bUODtzAcCC3qS7JAg568pfYIHRg8f3AfhgzLLtECvDu1NMLO2S-ts1q8+9SXX4xfsfeY1r90OW7PZtl0VpHnWBP7ivVe67+5n1vqulAQAWP84a7Tun4JRHhQC+1ANQLAIAvdIQF7bwWQONa97aTTNH+MHkEwz4PUnmfh6j9D0QehoBcbj4qSWKhE+18T9SaiEAtr5IL5ngwDWwN5590X-cF1qeGeDyO8XV7JdXkANj-UBq+t-r7MePTeW-5KT51Lv0Ae9bZ20Dz3uvvcF9HcPgPQf0Ah7D1eKPX6Y8UZX43pPKe0+HQz3v7PwOj-58Pb73Txe31S9L9y8Z9I8F918691MG8E8kkIC28aQt9W9d9Ck+8VMB9v8h8St-c5MRdLpL9J8Jdw959F98ll9V9YCa8N929EDu9hZM8SNpdVE5dQdFcLcrd9ZDZVd1cOCVctd7dvs9dndDcHgQAQBmCzcldksVc7cddBCDd2CbdNd+wPdc8CAxDMC-di9A9g9Q8b9o8yCn928X9084QP9+9N11CT8-8z0LpScJ8KdK8oAAArNiB4HvWHDROAPSZvSgyA63CjMwtAiwn-WDaw-3KnSXS-WnHmRwlw8Mdw7hLwtfXw+-UwwLFQ9A0QkIwvLArQi-A8XQsAu-AwhPZ-fwV-bcNIrPcw+zLIjQ--EfWaOw-AhwvQuItwugjwkmbwuA+vQIg-VQuoqws-CI4PaIq6No1woWXGPHRInolIvo9I7PB4AAL3ELBzYOV2zSvW1wdzkJd3ziUIUM4KUU+BQhWLWNNw2JYEty2K4P4Md35CEPYKOLuOPXd0-0PzWPqJsO0Mv0KNvy5lSOgPgOT3KJMPoM+NUO+OGNyMaOaIPHJ0A0mPiM6LmOSKXygP6Jz3QJhN-xGOpzGK-QmLAPaOmOgC6PcHmMxP8KqP3xxM3QuOyNPzhPPx0LDyKKBJKNBOMLfzpKhNxLxNCLPyaPPXsORNJKmISM8OpNIKxMCxqOzSZJ+PCMJKiOJNiKlLRJlIxLlNpMhJRyiRUHQA0XyT4WAFmGb1AEgGTwLDtlIENLzTBOgD4R2gnF4CalEE0GyWLDuHQEdL5OdOKF4DdLLF4C9J9IBF4hAHcTbwSX2WohoSkJcCzyAA).

PS. *I've read the [iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers.git) just now, so I know that my implementation might be ugly ...*

*([same question in language zh-cn](https://www.zhihu.com/question/618716971))*

Comment: ① Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the code to be a [mre]; you don't need to include many methods if the issue can be demonstrated with a few. ② You are erroneously reusing references to iterators, which are stateful. You need to refactor to only consume an iterator once, possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRAlEW). Yes, that redoes all the iteration every time. If you want to memoize things to make it faster that's fine but out of scope for the question as asked.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I am editing to make it minimal and clear. I want the iterator be immutable, and the point is, I think it should be both mutable or both immutable but in fact it might be one of them and I can't understand why. Why I implement `dropUntil` by took then it will be mutable, but it will not when I implement it directly, I didn't see any diff, the `Stream` that return by `took` looks similar with the `Stream` return by `dropUntil` which is implement directly ... I just want to know its rule ...

Comment: Iterators are stateful, and therefore mutable. An immutable iterator doesn't make much sense (it would have to return the same value for all calls to `next()`!). If you want to re-iterate an iterable, you need to get a new iterator. Calling a generator function gives a new iterator, which is good. When you re-use a iterator that's already been consumed, it will be `done` as soon as you start, which is bad. I showed one way to fix it, by always re-running the generator and by *never* reusing an existing iterator. Does that explain it or not? Shall I write my answer or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I just test the code you give me and found another problem (if I implement `drop` by the new `dropUntil` just like the `take`), you can see [this](https://tsplay.dev/weLQeW), and same problem also appears on my own `Stream` ...

Comment: Right, okay, how about [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WGXAkw) (again, you cannot reuse iterators)

Comment: @jcalz you say *"When you re-use a iterator that's already been consumed, it will be `done` as soon as you start, which is bad."* so that's the reason why I cannot implement a `took` then make `take` and `drop` by this `took` ? So ... re-using a iterator that's already been consumed is not same as re-running a new generator ? Thank you, this is the answer I might want ...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you are trying to *re-use* [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator).  But iterators are [stateful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)), and once you call `iterator.next()`, the iterator advances and you can't necessarily get the earlier information back from the same iterator. So you never want to create a new `Stream` with an existing iterator, nor allow any of `Stream`'s methods to use an existing iterator. Instead you need to generate a new iterator for each operation.

Since your `Stream` already has a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) (`function*(⋯){⋯}`), you can just call it to get a new iterator.  And that means when you create a new `Stream` you should create a new generator function to go with it.

Here's a stripped-down version of your original code which does this for the methods that return new `Stream`s.  For example, `dropUntil()` keeps a reference to the original generator function and then calls it inside a new generator function:

```
dropUntil(when: Fn<T, boolean>): Stream<T> {
    const gen = this.generatorFunction;
    return new Stream
        (function* (): Generator<T> {
            const iterator = gen();
            while (true) {
                const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) return;
                if (when(head)) {
                    yield head;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (true) {
                const { value, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                yield value;
            }
        });
};
```

And `drop()` needs to do something similar, so as to not persist the state of the `count` variable:

```
drop(limit: number): Stream<T> {
    const thiz = this;
    return new Stream(function* () {
        let count = 0;
        yield* thiz.dropUntil(() => !(count++ < limit));
    });
}
```

(That uses [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) to delegate to the `dropUtil` generator.)

---

Now we can see that it works as desired:

```
const ps = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).dropUntil(x => x > 5);
console.log(ps.take(10)); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 
console.log(ps.take(10)); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15] 

const qs = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).drop(7);
console.log(qs.take(10)); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
console.log(qs.take(10)); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
console.log(qs.take(10)); // [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

const fibonacci = Stream.iterate([0, 1], ([a, b]) => [b, a + b]).map(([x]) => x);
const fs = fibonacci.drop(10);
console.log(fs.take(6)); // [55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]
console.log(fs.take(6)); // [55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610] 
console.log(fs.take(6)); // [55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610]
```

---

Note that this implementation performs all the calculations multiple times and does not attempt to cache any results for later reuse.  You can write your own iterable wrapper that takes an iterator and caches its elements in an array for replaying, but I consider this out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgCoBooCUB8UC8UAUYAXFEgJS7boDcAULQMYA2AhgM5tQDKwAThCwC2yTAG96USVAYB7OGz4BXBsBm9CvAJYA3FsGj8WAEzlMQUAOYQ4EXnrUxFcFZrkl8FHNgDi12-d4RClEoAF86WikoBT1NBihNfTt9ZBRMfE04RIAJASMSVCgAMxJ4VNJMMhIeQ2EkbHEoqP5gRV44KBsAd24+AUF8IqcXOQAqAiqoXxtktREoRqalpghgKAALPNwErOBc4zolpa71zRWCJQhgyKPbkE0IJiMNvMPbo83jbaL8T6MyN7vMKApqhAE3SShCRSIy8GRgACqcGAZ3wJ2spUQhQARjIZCsWHBKtU+kJ5oslrJ5GsrB08MBTmwAHS0-yqXiOZwouQg5qrNodbq9WoQ96DYbcuDjDwkaZsub1BaioGSKkKBJJALbWkeXkqk5naD4S7XFXvNVrEK6JiKCAkP5oEw2MLbRLy3hMmwAD2AuuVZqkmiKBCdVygLQFeoDCWDaM2cF+eTIpuj73uj2efyjqck2MMAGts2aoTmS6mDedjbxbSmc6q5OqrSwbRBHXJoKFXZr2Z6ID6-XXA7HQxQ8wJC-7o+mnlBrbai0cy0CwSDwtDJMAWPmIEiUUw4xjYFi0Lj8QIiZMkABtAC6StuFvDEDYiiYwAKt+2t+zj7ds142wMpozKsv+nIjAm4K3BWRomveKqPk2Lb2nkbbOp2eB-gEvb9lBKpBiG7ajgWERmvwL5vkyYCKGw6yJsYeFAgRB4Jn8yZQGOW7ZmutwRu0T4UcAq7rlAm7bvgTCaIIiQkHAiiCNitiXp+FJNCsayyE4ax4AAjNmfEdEBzJiTuyKoh4lBQAAhPgmnIgA1PZUAIFAknScAyarqRMJwmAElSTJnTyYpvCTDU-TkpO0gNmsQEAF6AYy+n8vxQrhUI4pcq4UoTPBQLqdFWnbAADAukjTkY4zxUysLwru5meNgNl2cAjnOa5AUeYxoLdVCoqCCwYAIAi6QlBcBSNVACK1k0j7xYlwHJa0qUQD06UDEMWVjLlqm3EUagEI+2hQDIwbVaBATgZKHgzWaFXFPg2jdbcS49cJopXlwIAKfiTJYeyd54BZXiiYyLJ+GBErZX6a6MA2Z5MkwMgWPgABEAC0mNY5jqNkPQj5gJweDrX93YQPgABMaBepZNNOTpZA1b59X7jTIM09gACs4JqgjSMo4TTImfgOnFZ5UAAPQS1AV4AGxoAA7GgAAcaAAJxoKLms6ZrVNQDpADMmsACya5zd5w-IfPI4QxlbuTovi1LMvy1AStQKrUAa-rxXa7rmtG-rpv6+bUD4zFUAAI5E8K-Sk2y5N62z2B0-rjO1X5Cs8-DKyIzb0dC-bItiwCkvS1e3ta-rOv63rhsm2bmuuzp7s6crN6W2w1sowXwuO6XzsV5rvvV-7+uBzpwc6ZzTea637ed93+C90X-fUGXMuVyPOk1zpdcT1PM-68388d53axFJouJwCwDAMJo2wk-95NXtvN5oPgV4sCeN6TVe2JoBYFAJy2Jf5MgGn5T+Xpf602ztSYoMdL7X1vvfJm8Ji5wK7rnfmgw7biVlk7cunMj7K0rsbYOFMDaBwNgrd2stRYd15tgm2RQ8HkwIQPIhJCyEUKoWgGhdCGFhyYRAPOKNWGF3wYQmWxCVY8LQJQ6htC0D0OKhbWgN9BDPjALfaAABZFgIBFLoAgP9A6qlQCQCPOULA2xCATUsjQegopNoQSfGYwI9QMgkAAJKamxCseYAAfKAfj3TBIIMDbAYT-xBEmDElgASIAJPZJFB8EcPF2MsRAU6CRcA4DwKjVxkpcZQAAPwJAsu4L6P0mDx3-DsBIFAKmaE+t9XEdSPE3iqQkH8EcGC302PkUgn48DfiigVZsTAAAi7ZvjNjYBAPp8DaTfChttCyu0jj7QAhJVYeS8ClVEtWJZCRHK3XwrGB+LkBkMCGYjawFgGQXKnA8GctyhlXk0DeMq5o5AojkksqKL1gVHGYlM2ZNgKAGV+VERCs5my2jQh2Ls7ocK+mepcwiUK8p1ghXM+kJzYVHBhaCpYr0zQfIgEYKiNE6JziuMS8qbzngMt+RSqQHLJAGSgAAeWxAAKwgCoJk7A2CaAsAmHUZA0BbKWG02p9SAg3hILSKKK5RR9WcXC1gHBY5knqOIKKRhhWsH4E+YwphzAKo6UqgG7hJopIVJgZZChqwqDUBkfxKxfHeogEEXFtwjI2t+l01Fdgkkhs6d2NQHcXreSWDEFE8Rn6pHSJkHIeQChoDGmUQo9QwqkjqA0MlT5lqClWvqgY-APGZQgtKSYcpYmKjle8AqfxXS7H2EYJlUAYIXBOS8gM90syltuB2vAPw2K9p4iqMEmLIQiSiBnFmLFMTlFPASC8JJahpIQhHea9Ikqlp5WlItY6pD4BrTG9QxTsoNtlBDAIe7By-hvQtOKUa7WxoHIOPtpxKxwVbTmeFDKULGGRS6TCN70W-r-UObFYZSXwaiMxdErEkxDvgyO14F7oycQnChzleHQQkaiP2qsNZA1-tA4i1sUBQxQY1Gi70GLe23GYiODiJEyNHHumy3ji7SyeXVQmpoJlV3ofXTiPEW7iQjLvMBqQj5yKvnfApr8PzS1vvdAtNgX6ulwfeBRoDJHaPIReBBhjcyMLMf-LBhd7xONEW4+OMTZFnxqdpbRei-xe1ofjL59iBH2W-J5apt83El1SGFnAWSwUlIfkU6WgqLVth6RPSlQyYMJNmX3FE6ytkZBaTai5OAIn43as5WJiWowooExjk-MmlNqaWSK1bZhKMvQyqgKnBm6dmZ5fwMnQrNMXIUwq0cERYjbaSIdiXdeg89aB2DkfV27tPZb21hbdJHXRE4MFn3BbG8rzLbQKtlRisVbq2HttsOURRgS3oKEIAA)

Comment: Thanks. But, as you've said in comments, *"re-use a iterator **that's already been consumed**"* is the real point. So, *why a iterator **that's already been consumed** will have different behavior when I use it to make a new iterator ?* What's the meaning of *"it will be `done` as soon as you start"* ? (And Thanks to you, I've tried to clean some excess part in my question :) )

Comment: The point is what I said, that `iterator`s are stateful, and `iterator.next()` mutates the iterator and you can't necessarily "rewind" it.  One that's already been consumed completely is a special case of that (e.g., `iterator.next()` until done).  A generator function is not itself an iterator, it *makes* iterators.  So you can reuse a generator function as much as you want, but each result should only be used once.

Comment: for example ... first, I have a iterator, it's `[1,2,3,4,...]`, then, I take two element. This will make the next `iterator.next()` be `4` and its next is `5` ... so, I think I might can use this iterator instance as a param (or some thing other) for a generator function, and let it create a new iterator instance. I knows that iterator is must mutable, so I just wans to create a new to make my `stream` instance **looks like** immutable, just like the `map` or the new `dropUntil` methods did (if they are ...).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite understanding you (maybe it's a language barrier?) and I've explained what's going on about as well as I can to you, multiple times in multiple ways.  I don't think I know how to do it any better.  You don't need to accept my answer, but I think I need to disengage now, since further discussion doesn't seem likely to be useful to either of us. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe ... I'm sorry about that. Things is simple: ①, I need a drop method; ②, It can be implement by the logic of `take` (and I call it `took`: implement a `took` to return 2 things, one for take one for drop); ③, It was meant to be over here, but I found a problem: the `stream` object the `took(...)[1]` return is not same as another (such as `map` return), I want to know why. ④, Your `dropUntil`'s return (I am not mean a iterator object here) looks immutable, but how to do same thing by the *made drop by took* way ? I really want to see how can do same thing in `took` method ...

Comment: I agree with your rights about the disengage, but if not trouble, you can make a answer for this question. If you think this discussion really doesn't seem likely to be useful, just ignore my replies is well :)

Answer (score 0):

I found *the point of the diff* that an answer of this confusion needed !!

I just add a method. Here is 2 cases

case one:

```
    readonly dropX = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : Stream<T> => 
    {
        // const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
        
        return new Stream
        (( function* (this: Stream<T>)
        : Generator<T> 
        {
            const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                if (when(head)) { yield head ; break; } ;
            } ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                yield value ;
            } ;
        } ).bind(this)) ;
    } ;
```

case two:

```
    readonly dropX = 
    (when: Fn<T, boolean>)
    : Stream<T> => 
    {
        const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
        
        return new Stream
        (( function* (this: Stream<T>)
        : Generator<T> 
        {
            // const iterator = this.generatorFunction() ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value: head, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                if (when(head)) { yield head ; break; } ;
            } ;
            
            while (true) 
            {
                const { value, done } = iterator.next();
                if (done) break;
                
                yield value ;
            } ;
        } ).bind(this)) ;
    } ;
```

They have same test code:

```
const x = Stream.iterate(2, x => x + 1).dropX(x => x > 3) ;
console.log(x.take(5)); // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
console.log(x.take(5)); // case one: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8] or case two: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

#### Try some summary

It looks the diff of `Stream` is depends on where the `generatorFunction` be called:

- If it is instde of the new `function*` define, then the `Stream` made by this function will looks immutable at `take`'s calling.
- If it is outside of the new `function*` define, then the `Stream` made by this function will looks mutable and mudt be muted while the `take` is call.

I don't know more reason about *why this feature*, but it finish my quest. The most I want is to control this different behavior, just this.

*(And because of the "I don't really know why", this answer will not be most helpful, this question will still open.)*

*[Here is my link: https://tsplay.dev/WPBKZN](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAPAFQDRQEoD4oF4oAUYAXFMgJR44ZQDcAsAFBMDGANgIYDOXUAysABOEDgFsmKHEwDeTKPKhyFLAPZwuQgK4tgKwYsYLCYQQEsAbh2DRhHACZq2IKAHMIcCIKt6YmuDtM1UgJKXBwAcXdPb0FJSiV5aQBfOgSDIzSNK1MWKFsHOCcoU2svazx0hRRUHAJTOBKACRE7UjQoADNSeGqyLHI00gFbUUkqSqN5NKMPAHd+IRFxQ0n5Ak6-ALUAKkIBldXSSI8yvTHphVkD1YU2CGAoAAsWivqmloZrm6hZx9M7whaCDxL43K7fb4gUwQNh2J4vT4Qm7PewVDoEFF2ciIpFQFI41YpSgEiak-KOZyiDhgCppRAYGqELqwOC9bD7IxDRZiek4MKkjKg+RzBYjC5rdYdTbAQJwXYEYB-LhckZxcVQI5RU6xbACy7qoyqdQPErRXT6fCK0xcAB0bhOMV8-hlahCqSFk1+-2gCsEmmBetW4NxhrUGig0igljY-tImPQBWgKXwpu1No8AA9gCESSHTB1CInKAAjWwAa1zuINNyhMLh6MxxOr8nx6qJNuL9TsCqV5Cb1zSg+u5MKzjsghUYAAqnAZWwAPoADVp1wIv3c3VZ7WLKhUdw4cH6g1FSzG-LSwdWAHor1AjeHUzEKlbbfazT5pbK3ZWph7hMBNEEBARWGJZ1QISVPx2QElRVU9kCPD1NQdc1zg9S8IXvE1SifS0lTtLVHSguBv2bQNPT+AFfX9EEQwwkMsIjKMOBjCA4xaBM1CTV4cPNdMICzHMyKMfNCy4ktyx-CFhIUUS12eEjG0oSNa1heFUVoKBSxECs8XdENWw9QUQy9KigVo3F6NxRjI2jf1OI8PSU14vR+ME7EZPkOSiy0yTPPIyFoTUuzoCkoxDO+dtOzgbsXz7fSFAihQRyKcdJxnOd5wATRXIx5I3Fleh3PcREPDkFDgnkEPGC91UYx9zWffC321J0thI-tvnVf9AOAiB5lAsRwMg51ZXlF9KtGBDysOKBjnfWJqvVKzr1veqXItKAXwIlCP1G11OqrIyFFMn1zIC-VjtWGzmNY9j7Ac7jnIWtzsw8q7Jm88TfJ0sKbn8uT10Ulp4pUoK4UxOgfo4XSkqROHpI+07AT9AMyJWzCwweWyWPsqBEyc4oNteoSPpEgsCB87SYb+1Z-NUuEQoS+HmcmKKux7a14pJBGUrHCcwCXXKFAINhTFEEpSDgTRRGLTwZo1E8qr5KRrgxxjFWgPDrVZoweqAqAQO5UQCClfa5T2ciMfJwgxYlh5ECgABGCykTButdk1naFral0OqhlIYS4aB0f8u4HlUPwHnwJ3acmBnPeeG00unWd-iXCDQlqSPZwAalzqAcDtko+zjhHwsOltWb5-GBey4W1mL4ApZluXBAVyaz1Vox1axrbnianWpP1vqBuN03iPlV3Jmt2SKabpBnen753dhROIG91riO-PSg5Dj7Z9WcO7xUKOKlj+nwfX5OBYy9Ossz8YCBz4B88LqAm9Lsjy8Syu9JJNINddAqDLHfNgDdCBA03EVXc+4yrHgANrIAQQAXXQINKaWAUE1TVnVPuwguCaDYM3MgqCKhkKkutBag9XyEXNL7L8f9jI3GRtRNG6EyI3RCvdOwj1CYNVcpmN6ccvoeAkr9MiZECFEOADaMAmguCPAxCDERFMgbKPsPFamFY2y6wUHg40tdJy8GetqPRv5vgjygAg6RxD0BGzFB6CCGxzbjVgkrTBCtORzToWcJaHCkaUTOqjZeYJ-JcNxhAPhyYjFgFtEI0mIYbaU2+touOzCklQAZrdf05i2a6PIB2DmcVyDoGwTzVmgCWgUi2ruMsEDRbi0lobVu8tEHILQR4yQ2Dzy4I9HJBejsXZWzyPcXq1jUHoG2h0PcbAVCzAIMkKA3AyCFOAWWAgLsEFOxQeU3ebBg5WzIsfF+5845WO2ussBj9+QAEJn6nzzgXR2n93qRVZgjIcetqmji2jDCAYCGlQMKtuWBpVELeI6TgrqHpLl1OuUDcgCCAAM5SvnJR+UUYA-yGlwBbrLNp1w2hkN6TC74cKQEEDgEi1FlSBzDkxfzScYB6guEBfgNI+U8UgvQMVOBEKKpdOqqS-6sL8JXLTmwLlSKdl0u+fYGpKcWVwBcA0pu+K24dyFSrci6oKUbM-tstF9KMlkkZbE9lpIuXQNBSVA8Ar5Cd2Fd3UV3wHFgScSNdqbjrROodZMZCC00Ir04X3ARm1totSIubUiH0yKsPOqHMmyg+44zuupXh+MuL8OJgkt5mTigUypn5ZNFiC2AwUhorEyksngwzVDNJ-9v55NNd8BNISLqJHCamnJUSs2ORieGkm+bMmiIDGk-yl86y9pbYlPJ7MYqcy4NzdF8ga4pzVU0kh0sCXt2PBgrupJe6GM1jQvJVj3ViAnq4y2y0yIDK3YvYZ6Na0e37hvKN9Dt7En2YcpNBaP73BPmfGO6SFAJ3fTfdKkqbnZ0ea-AuRct1fw+j-Fsf9Pkmv0dcG8UAuAqFENAVQdhoBwBUA8cwnhnDizAHobFs54TCCgDaFjq7RkKt+VwFgB4GnMgIBwFgLA2joAzG0LOqz93G0PeqdUl7ljfGcWbb1MFfXaq8YK+a2pg1hI+lQsx2taG7UEAwg6s75ARPTfGftT0iYvTzaosSYjRkASAnHY5QGBO5HwJiOO2TPNmc7T8IJKMaKBcPpMCzsYM3RJ4nZgSwiAZFtSSWgD-l-P4HRJ59AjYwPyD84JgLaG9KFOirFXsf82M1xmWpDlq4+OeeE1AUTqzxjtDeMAZo9gxOSdVM63VHo5PDRccppdfr1OOp8UZ7TQZJEfWye1zrcJfNX37taG0XGDymyYa6m4C6ytcwq1htd5rqtzPmLVvKmJutEu1dCnbqxpl7m7AQecInxMZmyyDOV2HTUIL4CAWWe4bThp6ZbfkkbfHGe-e6QyrAwwlRtHMlwBAABEABaDHmOsfY7Ryj-YTBcMbpo3cQjDG7CmGEDoJwTA4eGKVRAOwYChb4AwcD3iEACAACYRPjAzFAAuLsoOp0youAgfP+R85wAAZn7PeBHSPKYC0gIzyVS4bTYrLBzp2yLS5QFwwggALOgAArOgAAbOgAA7OgAAHOgAAnOgbXTunZO+587KXKDaf4buIjlQyP6cq5F+r-5mydfYj17eQ3JvzdW9tw7p3yKXdu6d5773DxA9M5yiz42bOzQc-d+LnAfOBeFJTlnsXvP34y-dHL33CvM+q6yiHzXYfdf66N1AU3UALdQGt1AO3UBHfOyT87V3zt3dOzT4wOvG8G9K4Z1nlvWvw+aX107TvTtu9O1707fvTtB9O2H5z0fnPx+c-d5z6f6fYnK+Zx4vPZQC884l-zpeQuM6W9l-D+v-vFfMoZzVw1xX3byj2H2dzHxTw9yd03231333xty9xnx-znz-0DyAND211AOsXANHydnHydknylxgKdzgKdwQKQMYnQOzwfwamfyayr1Lw-wfi-1rxQL9wDwXzsGymXzbwj311wOTwn1TxIOdjIOdgoO93lzQK4J4OAL4LXzAMTyEMIJEOdlgKd3gKd0QJp0YEJzrhygKAAHIHg5kQFeAxZNcLUm8oBUACdbw5ZuMFFoBT1P09p2piheAyMHg5Y7wWI7g4RT5gAuBTASN31hs-ZdgbQmAgA)*

---

And ... how about cache feature ? I'd rather use memoize to the take method, only if the form as `a.b(c,d)` is totally same as `b(a,c,d)` in JS/TS while `b` is defined as `b(this, x, xx)`.

But this is another question. :)